# how to use linear programming for Heaviside Step function and L1 norm?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to find a hyperplane that can divide my sets of points into 2 groups that have nearly equal size. If the hyperplane is $w$, there is a scalar offset $b$. I have $N$ points that are $d$-dimensional denoted by $x_i$. $\delta(.)$ is an Heaviside Step function, ie. if $x \geq 0$, $\delta(x)=1$ else $\delta(x)=0$.

so I pose my requirement as:
$\sum_{x_i}\delta(w^T x_i +b)=\sum_{x_i}\delta(-w^Tx_i-b)$

But as points are either in the left or the right half (right half includes the hyperplane itself), I can write:

$\sum_{x_i}\delta(w^T x_i +b)=\sum_{x_i}1-\delta(w^Tx_i+b)$

$\implies 2\times \sum_{x_i}\delta(w^T x_i +b)=N $

Now I do not know how to remove the step function to bring it into a simple linear programming form. Any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Note that the subgradient of the absolute value function is $2\delta - 1$, so your condition is equivalent to the optimality condition of this optimization problem:
$$
\min_{b} \sum_i |w^T x_i + b|
$$
If necessary, this can be expressed as a linear program:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\min_{b, y_i} \sum_i y_i\\
-y_i \le w^T x_i + b \le y_i
\end{gathered}
$$
As long as the points are unique, a randomly chosen direction $w$ will suffice to separate the points. (That is, if $w$ is chosen uniformly on the sphere, then with probability $1$, $w^T x_i \ne w^T x_j$ for any $i\ne j$.)